# SSRS - An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Tags: sql-server, ssrs-2016

I have an SSRS report that renders for most jobs, but there is one job that errors out. The report runs briefly for this particular job, then returns the "Cannot read the data row for the dataset ."

The error log shows

> Cannot read the next data row for the dataset . --->
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: A transport-level error has
>   occurred when receiving results from the server. (provider: TCP
>   Provider, error: 0 - An existing connection was forcibly closed by the
>   remote host.) ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: An existing
>   connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

The query runs correctly in SSMS, and the report renders correctly for all the other jobs that I've tested.

Has anyone experienced any other like this issue before? Any ideas on what could cause this in a specific case?

Any insight is greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: This happens occassionally, or every time?   And what do you mean by "job"?   I don't know how you might associate an SSRS report with a Job.

Comment: Every time in this particular instances. By "job", I mean a project in our line of business (think marketing promotion), not SQL job.

Comment: So, to be clear, this error happens consistently when you choose certain parameter value(s) in the report, regardless of the time of day or the client computer?   Does it only happen on the SSRS server, or does it also happen in Visual Studio?    By the way, when asking a question on SO, it's best to avoid using terms that are only meaningful to someone in your company.   Right now it's unlikely anyone can help you because there isn't enough information in your question to reproduce the issue.

Comment: There are a few layers between your report and your data.  We will need more details about those to help you isolate and troubleshoot. Please tell us if there is anything unique to the failing report, WRT data location (same server or different, or linked server, or filestore) permission, authentication, connection, etc.